# I'm a sysadmin wanting to learn some web-development,better Asp Webforms or MVC/RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm a windows/unix sysadmin wanting lo learn some web development.Here is a list of what i'm planning to learn and want to do :

- i'm planning to do that only as a hobby,for a couple of personal applications and my office little "intranet" (phone book,list of machines,a list of useful links and a password protected area for reserved info)
- i only have a basic understanding of html (i can read and modify it without problems but not writing it as a web developer),no javascript/css
- i used Ruby on Rails 2.x for the actual little office intranet,with a lot of copy and paste of html/css and a lot of scaffolding...so i know only the base of the old RoR
- i'm developing on a Windows machine and wanna rebuild from scratch my little application adding some new useful stuff (like a community space for news,info and comments)
- i will be on vacation in 5 days and wanna read about something new :)

So i'm considering asp.net webforms 4.0 because i have little to no knownledge of frontend languages. I know that is not considering good habit now,but i really do not wanna learn first html/css/javascript,it's just an hobby as i told you before

I've considered too Ruby on Rails 3.0,but i really hate TDD development idea and there is still the html-css-javascript problem

What can you suggest me ?

Comment: Please re-check the [faq]. This type of question is not on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is not what you want to hear but I only have what you posted to go on and it seems like development is not for you. Programmers LOVE learning new technologies and playing with great languages. If you don't then find another hobby.

You start by saying essentially you have a basic idea of HTML. You want to write an intranet site. You don't want to learn HTML and CSS ?

But that's all a website is. The rest is just tools that enable you to product the HTML and css.

Perhaps you need to reconsider writing web sites ?

> I've considered too Ruby on Rails 3.0,but i really hate TDD
>   development idea and there is still the html-css-javascript problem

Why would the fact that you hate TDD mean you can't use Rails 3? That just doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

If you have a real interest in this as a hobby then you need to learn HTML and CSS whichever tool you use to produce your application with.

TDD is good. Why do you hate it?
If you really hate learning new stuff then I guess you need to find a different hobby or choose a different solution to your intranet. i.e. non web based intranet.

Delphi, and .net platforms spring to mind but if you struggle with HTML you'll certainly not find object pascal or c# easy to pick up.

Best advice I can give you is don't do it.
Hobbies should be fun and you are really saying that you don't want to learn new languages like HTML, CSS, Rails etc...

If you really do want to do this then either bite the bullet and learn HTML/CSS as you develop your site using Rails 3 as this will handle all your database activities very nicely. You can add javascript when you feel more comfortable.

If you really don't want to learn how to write websites but still want to develop yout intranet which is pretty much what your question is saying, then try ruby, Delphi or .net and write a non web based intranet multi tier app.

**Update based on comments below**

Based on on your comment I strongly suggest you go with webforms. You are familiar with C# and the tone of your question is I don't understand Rails. Seems pretty much like you have made up your mind already anyway.

I'll just add that you should try these things for yourself rather than rely on opinions. You need to form your own opinion on what you like the best. Just make sure that opinion is based on fact. It worries me that you would think some of the things you have mentioned with regards to Rails.

Comment: Probably i wrote it badly...i love learning new stuff! I was  just thinking that learning the whole html5 + css3 for just writing a little intranet application is an overkill..maybe i have to rethink this. Was asking about webforms cause it appears involving only c# (that i know ) without too much html/css

Comment: I guess all you can really do is try them out for yourself and see what you prefer. Personally I love ruby more way more than I like C# but it's personal taste. Go with what you are comfortable with.